# Issue with iterating map in visualforce page. VF page is Not getting save

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have below code in my VF page -

```
<tbody>
  <apex:repeat value="{!objVsFieldsMap}" var="key" id="theObjReapter1">
     <tr>
       <td>{!key}</td>
       <apex:repeat value="{!objVsFieldsMap[key]}" var="lstVal">
         <td><p>{!lstVal.val}</p></td>
       </apex:repeat>
     </tr>
  </apex:repeat>
</tbody>
```

And I'm not able to save the VF page. It shows me `Syntax error.  Found 'objVsFieldsMap'`. 
The strange thing is the same kind of code is working for other VF page. Any idea about it?

Comment: Best you add the Apex declaration of `objVsFieldsMap` to the question: are its values a collection?

Comment: Share the apex code for this map?

Comment: Got resolved. I don't know what was wrong. I just created another VF page and copied code from the current one which had issue. Anyway thanks every one.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the same key store the ids in set or any other do something like this

```
public class toda {
Public Map<Id,Account> acc {get;set;}
public set <Id> ids {get;set;}
public toda ()
{
    ids  = new Set<Id>();
    acc = New   Map<Id,Account>([Select Id,Name From Account limit 100]);
 for(Account acc :acc .Values() {
  ids .add(acc.Id);
 }
}}
```

Use that Id in place of key